# Why is there an empty graph when ploting a graph for the predicted result?

Tags: python-3.x

Below is my written code that I am trying to plot the actual and the predicted values in the LSTM algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
np_array= np. add(y_true,y_pred)
no_of_pred =24
ind=72
y_pred= forecast(x_val,no_of_pred,ind)
y_true = y_val[ind:ind+(no_of_pred)]
y_true = np_array.reshape(1, -1)
y_true= y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_true)
y_pred = np_array.reshape(1, -1)
y_pred= y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
def plot(y_true,y_pred):
  ar = np.arange(len(y_true))
  plt.figure(figsize=(22,10))
  plt.plot(ar, y_true,'r')
  plt.plot(ar, y_pred,'y')
  plt.show()
plot(y_true,y_pred)
```

Unfortunately, a graph is drawn that has X and Y axis, but empty with no lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the following rows correctly:

```
y_pred = np_array.reshape(1, -1)
y_pred= y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

`y_pred` has shape `(1, n)`.

I then test you function `plot` with arrays of that shape:

```
def plot(y_true, y_pred):
    ar = np.arange(len(y_true))
    plt.figure(figsize=(22,10))
    plt.plot(ar, y_true,'r')
    plt.plot(ar, y_pred,'y')
    plt.show()
    
plot(np.array([[1, 2, 3]]), np.array([[4, 5, 6]]))
```

Output plot is indeed empty:
[image]

(`ar` inside `plot` function is that case is equal to `[0]` also)

Testing the same function with arrays of shape `(n, )`:

```
def plot(y_true, y_pred):
    ar = np.arange(len(y_true))
    plt.figure(figsize=(22,10))
    plt.plot(ar, y_true,'r')
    plt.plot(ar, y_pred,'y')
    plt.show()
    
plot(np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]))
```

Output plot now looks correctly:
[image]

So my suggestion is to reshape arrays once again from `(1, n)` to `(n,)`, for example like that:

```
def plot(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = y_true.reshape((y_true.shape[1],))
    y_pred = y_pred.reshape((y_pred.shape[1],))
    ar = np.arange(len(y_true))
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
    plt.plot(ar, y_true,'r')
    plt.plot(ar, y_pred,'y')
    plt.show()

plot(np.array([[1, 2, 3]]), np.array([[4, 5, 6]]))
```

Output looks like graph 2 (correct one).

Comment: I applied your suggestion and it worked but I applied it on another dataset and it gave me the same graph with same lines, I don't know what's the problem.